# How does MobileMe dynamically scale font size of their username login field?

Tags: javascript, css

I noticed when logging into www.me.com the username input field scales down the font when you hit the end of the input field.  It's amazingly accurately, almost detecting character widths, so it's not character counting.  It even works on unicode chars.  Do you know how it's done?

Comment: https://auth.me.com/my/loginForm/en-us/2E11/javascript-packed.js

Is this a custom library?

Comment: Yes, and it happens to have a notice up top that basically says "don't go copying our code".  Even if you wanted to use their code (I'm not saying you should), there are a couple(few?) dependencies they are utilizing for the functionality asked of by the OP. Easier just to come up with the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

They:

1. put the value of the username input in a span element positioned off page
2. make the span element have the same font-size as the input
3. get the width of the span element
4. determine if the span's width is greater than the "useable" width of the input element, and update the font-size accordingly

Comment: The code that does this is in the javascript on the page itself: `getContentMetrics:function(el,altStr,useWidth){var str=(typeof altStr==="string")?altStr:el.innerHTML,span=$.metricSpan||(function(){$.metricSpan=$.htmlElement('<div id="$metricSpan" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; top:-10000px;"></div>');
document.body.appendChild($.metricSpan);...`

Comment: That function is only one piece of it, but yes, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked something very similar here: [How to resize text in a textbox if it is too large till a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072106/)

So I made a small library that allows to write:

```
<input type="text" resize="true" />
```

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164769/1344937