# How to resize text in a textbox if it is too large till a certain size

Tags: javascript, jquery

[`https://auth.me.com/authenticate`](https://auth.me.com/authenticate)

On this website when you type in your email address , the font-size will automatically be reduced if the email address fills the box size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- How can we do the same using Javascript?
- which are the events that are being fired / captured ?

Comment: very good question because when you type `f`s you can go to 36 but with `o`s you can go to 17. So the answers based on the number of letters aren't good.

Comment: I was working for a better solution than the one from Calvein (you can see in his fiddle, when the font-size is small and then you erase what you wrote, the font-size doesn't become bigger). Do I continue, or you will never come here and un-accept the solution from Calvein to accept mine? Please answer. N.B: My solution is really better, believe me.

Comment: @Mageek I will come here as i check stackoverflow very often and stackoverflow have the notification system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a library, named <kbd>resize.js</kbd>, which allow to write:

```
<input type="text" resize="true" />
```

---

This is the library:

```
var precision=18;

window.onload=function()
{
    for(var i=0,t=document.getElementsByTagName("input"),l=t.length;i<l;i++)if(t[i].getAttribute("resize")==="true")
    {
        var div=document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("style","font-size"+parseInt(t[i].s("font-size"))+";font-family:"+t[i].s("font-family")+";position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-10000px;");
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        (function(i,div,min,max,dif,l,r,w,h,pre){setInterval(function(){modify(t[i],div,min,max,dif,l,r,w,h,pre);},100);})
        (
            i,
            div,
            t[i].getAttribute("min")||parseInt(t[i].s("font-size"))-3,
            t[i].getAttribute("max")||parseInt(t[i].s("font-size")),
            parseInt(t[i].s("padding-left"))+parseInt(t[i].s("padding-right"))+parseInt(t[i].s("border-left-width"))+parseInt(t[i].s("border-right-width"))+precision,
            parseInt(t[i].s("padding-left")),
            parseInt(t[i].s("padding-right")),
            t[i].offsetWidth,
            t[i].offsetHeight,
            precision
        );
    }
}
Object.prototype.s=function(p)
{
    return this.currentStyle?this.currentStyle[p]:document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue(p);
}
function modify(el,c,min,max,dif,l,r,w,h,pre)
{
    el.style.width=w+"px";
    el.style.height=h+"px";
    c.innerHTML=el.value.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/ /g,"&nbsp");
    var test=c.offsetWidth;
    while(test>=el.offsetWidth-dif&&parseInt(el.s("font-size"))>min)
    {
        el.style.fontSize=parseInt(el.s("font-size"))-1+"px";
        c.style.fontSize=el.style.fontSize;
        test=c.offsetWidth;
    }
    while(test<el.offsetWidth-dif&&parseInt(el.s("font-size"))<max)
    {
        el.style.fontSize=parseInt(el.s("font-size"))+1+"px";
        c.style.fontSize=el.style.fontSize;
        test=c.offsetWidth;
    }
    if(parseInt(el.s("font-size"))===min&&c.offsetWidth>el.offsetWidth-dif)
    {
        el.style.paddingLeft="0px";
        el.style.paddingRight="0px";
    }
    else
    {
        el.style.paddingLeft=l+"px";
        el.style.paddingRight=r+"px";
    }
}
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/GEp2y/1

---

Some advices:

- If the attribute "resize" equals anything other than true, or is not set, the text-box will behave as a normal text-box.
- You can set the maximum font-size and the minimum font-size allowed by setting the "max" and the "min" attributes. By default, the maximum is the current font-size and the minimum is 3 sizes smaller than the maximum.
- I added something, like https://auth.me.com/authenticate, which removes the padding to gain space when the minimum font-size is reached.
- There is the variable 'precision' (at the beginning of resize.js) that depends on the text-box, I set it to 18 for default text-box but if you modify the style of the text-box, you will maybe have to modify the variable to a better value (by testing).
- I don't ensure the host of resize.js on the website like in the fiddle, you should copy the source code in a new file and save it.

Comment: Hey, this is really old now but how would you go about doing this for a text area with a fixed width and height? I've modified the script to include textarea elements, but it still tries to fit in on a single line. I would like it to work like this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XCXJb/1/ but this one is not capable of adjusting the font size back up when you delete characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
if(this.value.length>43)//or some other value
{//do stuff here
}
});
```

Keydown is what you are looking for

Comment: Might be better to use "keypress", as that'll happen after things like the backspace key, etc. Also might be good to handle "cut" and "paste".

Answer (score 1):

I've made the code for you, I took for example what I did on my [own website](http://francois.robichet.com#contact) for the contact form: the `<textarea>` gets taller if there is lot's of text.

The thing to do is to create an invisible`<div>`, for each `keydown` in the `<input>`, take its content and puts it into the `<div>`, and check its `width` is bigger than the `<input>`'s one.

The HTML

```
<form>
    <input>
    <div></div>
</form>
​
```

The CSS where we set the same font-size for the `<input>` and the `<div>` and hide the `<div>` (with `position: absolute` because we need it's width and we don't want it to change the layout)

```
form > * {
    font-size: 22px
}

form > input {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

form > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}​
```

And the JavaScript (with jQuery here)

```
var $form = $('form')
  , $input = $('input', $form)
  , $autoResize = $('div', $form)
  , $both = $input.add($autoResize)
  , fontSize = parseInt($input.css('font-size'), 10)

$input.on('keydown', function() {
    $autoResize.html(this.value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                                .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                                .replace(/ {2,}/g, function(spaces) {
                                    // Change the spaces to $nbsp; except the last one
                                    for (var i = 1, fakeSpaces = '', space; space = spaces[i++];) {
                                        fakeSpaces += '&nbsp;'
                                    }
                                    return fakeSpaces + ' '
                                })
                            )
    // We add 10px to be sure it doesn't stick to the edges
    if ($autoResize.outerWidth() >= $input.outerWidth() - 10) {
        do {
            $both.css('font-size', --fontSize)
        } while ($autoResize.outerWidth() >= $input.outerWidth() && fontSize > 10)
        // 10px is the smallest font-size accepted
        if (fontSize === 10) {
            $input.off('keydown')
        }
    }
})​
```

Here is [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/EPFr9/).

Comment: Nice :) we might need to make the font size back to bigger if that text if being deleted or backspace until it can fit the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You must use JavaScript to count how much characters've been typed already (I believe with `.change()` in jQuery) and change the font-size accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I think what @somebody is in trouble is doing is what they are doing in here.

- Calculate how many letters will fit into the box -  you know the width of the textbox. You know the font-size & padding that is being given here. So you know how many letters can be typed in the textbox before it overflows( not exactly) .
- Or you can just type random letters & see how many can fit ! :)
- Well, if you have time, you can as well dive into the events being fired when you keydown on the email address text box. You will learn a lot!